# Java List fitering

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Java and I have created a list like

```
List<TruckCategoriesModel> catvals = truckcatesq.getLocationTruckCategories("tryone"));
```

My `TruckCategoriesModel` contains

```
private String category,header_loc;
private int db_id;
//getters and setters for the above
```

Now after some calculations I have several indexes with represent category. I have a list in which contains a list e.g.

```
fruit, juice, mango
```

Which I got by

```
private List<String> truckcategories = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int j=0; j<catvals.size(); j++){
      truckcategories.add(catvals.get(j).getCategory());
}
```

So after clicking on the above list(`truckcategories`) am setting up another integers of indexes of the specific list item so

```
fruit  //gets 0
, juice //gets 1
```

So my integers i have are

```
Integer[] selecteditems = [0,1....]//the selected items
```

So, now I want to know how to filter the old `List<TruckCategoriesModel> catvals = truckcatesq.getLocationTruckCategories("tryoone"));`  per the `selecteditems` indexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the following original list:

```
List<TruckCategoriesModel> catvals = new ArrayList<>();
catvals.add(new TruckCategoriesModel("fruit", "s1", 1));
catvals.add(new TruckCategoriesModel("juice", "s2", 2));
catvals.add(new TruckCategoriesModel("mango", "s3", 3));
```

you loop should generate the following `truckcategories`:

```
[fruit, juice, mango]
```

Then now if you want to filter on 1 (which is `juice`)

```
int filterIndex = 1; // juice

// lookup the corresponding category string
String filterCategory = truckcategories.get(filterIndex);

// filter
List<TruckCategoriesModel> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
for(TruckCategoriesModel tcm : catvals) {
  if(filterCategory.equals(tcm.getCategory())) {
    filteredList.add(tcm);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help just as i needed

Answer (score 1):

If you have a **minSdkVersion >= 24** and Java 8 support, then you can use Java 8 streams:

```
List<TruckCategoriesModel> filteredList = catvals.stream()
                        .filter(item -> filterCategory.equals(item.getCategory()))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or if you're using `RxJava2` library:

```
List<TruckCategoriesModel> filteredList = Observable.fromIterable(catvals)
                .filter(item -> filterCategory.equals(item.getCategory()))
                .toList()
                .blockingGet();
```

These are a little advanced methods, but worth checking.